# /t͡ʃ/ vs. /ʧ/ vs. /tʃ/

Tags: ipa, phonetic-symbols

In English for example, the "ch" sound (as in *China*) is sometimes written as /t͡ʃ/, other times as /ʧ/ or simply as /tʃ/. Similarly, I have seen the German "tz" (e.g. *Katze*) transcribed as /t͡s/, /ʦ/ and /ts/.

Is there an "official" recommendation on which option should be considered correct?

Comment: I can highly recommend [this book](https://langsci-press.org/catalog/book/176) for Unicode topics in linguistics.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"tʃ", "t͡ʃ", and "t͜ʃ" are the only representations of the affricate currently sanctioned by the International Phonetic Association. The ligature symbols "ʧ", "ʦ", etc. were removed from the alphabet at the [1989 Kiel Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_International_Phonetic_Alphabet#1989_Kiel_Convention).

The arches in "t͡ʃ, t͜ʃ" are called tie bars. Note the IPA chart says "Affricates and double articulations can be represented by two symbols joined by a tie bar *if necessary*" (emphasis added). They are essential in languages where an affricate phoneme and a homorganic stop–fricative sequence frequently contrast, such as Polish, but otherwise they are omitted more often than not. I do not know of any dictionary of English or German that makes use of them.

Answer (score 20):

In theory, the difference between /t͡ʃ/ with a tiebar and /tʃ/ without is that the former represents a single unit and the latter represents two units. This is sometimes important for theoretical reasons (you might want to treat /t͡ʃ/ as a unit because it lets you make some phonological generalizations) and more rarely for practical ones (Polish contrasts affricates against stop-fricative clusters: /ˈt͡ʂɨsta/ "clean", /ˈtʂɨsta/ "300").

In practice, most people don't bother to write the tie bar unless it's important (as in Polish). So I've seen both /t͡ʃ/ and /tʃ/ in different transcriptions of English, without any meaningful implication.

/ʧ/, the single character, is obsolete and no longer part of the IPA. But it would mean the same thing as /t͡ʃ/ with a tie bar: a single affricate unit rather than a stop followed by a fricative.

Comment: Wonderful! Allow me to expand. Polish *trzysta* "300" continues PSlav. \*tri-  akin to *three* from \*treyes, where *rz* is a digraph, but *czysty* "clean" continues PSlav. \*čìstъ akin to  Latvian *šķîsts* "thin, clear, clean, vel sim. apparently from PIE \*skeyd- (according to wiktionary).¹ So, it looks like they come from very different clusters, except that both changes seem to be conditioned by front(ed semi-)vowels. See palatization and assybilation: *mega, maioris; \*cansmn, carmen; \*kaput, chapel; hio, she; \*hwaz, who*; indeed *Sino-, China*. Polish maintains the theory in practice.

Comment: 1: I would further compare Ger. *gescheit* "clever; proper", origin ultimately uncertain, and I remark doubts about s-mobile, satemization, glottalization, laryngeals and the nostratic-like hypothesis (cf. @anixx) that PIE \*H correspond with PSem \*t, noting that PSem \*š reads \*/ts/ (or \*/t͜s/?). Sanity check (cf. WT): Semitic "3" is somewhat uncertain, \*ṯalāṯ- or \*śalāṯ?! Further extra-familiar comparison notwithstanding, and despite a chance of wanderwords, I suggest to compare En *cutsy* (from Latin, from \*h₂eḱ- (“sharp”), according to opinio communitis [sounds like an illness]) JSYK

Comment: I am pretty sure the research has shown that in Polish we actually have /t͡ʂ/ and not/t͡ʃ/, contrary to Czech.

Comment: I think it would be useful to mention or explain the difference between // and [] here! :)

Answer (score 3):

The [2015 IPA chart](https://www.internationalphoneticassociation.org/sites/default/files/IPA_Kiel_2015.pdf) is freely available from the Association's website. It does not include affricate characters in the form of ligatures (such as ʧ and ʦ); it does include a note stating "Affricates and double articulations can be represented by two symbols joined by a tie bar if necessary", giving the examples "t͜s" and "k͡p". The implication is that if not necessary, affricates and double articulations may be represented by two symbols in sequence without a tie bar, like your examples of ts and tʃ.

There may be more detail in the 1999 Handbook; since it is not free, I have not read it. Wikipedia states without a source that the ligatures for [affricates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affricate) "are no longer standard IPA".